# hook_form_FORMID_alter not working

Tags: drupal, hook-form-alter

```
function send_xml_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state){
    $form["#submit"][] = 'send_xml_edit_account_submit_function';
    drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($form['#submit'], TRUE) . '</pre>');
}

function send_xml_edit_account_submit_function($form, &$form_state) {
    drupal_set_message(t("ahoy"));
}
```

the modules name is `send_xml.module`.

this code `drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($form['#submit'], TRUE) . '</pre>');` displays

```
Array
(
     [0] => user_profile_form_submit
     [1] => send_xml_edit_account_submit_function
)
```

but this code `drupal_set_message(t("ahoy"));` isnt displaying...

anyone ring a bell?

it's quite annoying to have problems which you cant find the reason why... does anyone experience this before? if yes, would please so kind to share your solutions to me. thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with the code you've pasted. I've tested it and it works fine ; I get "ahoy" displayed.

Suggestions:

- Try it on a fresh Drupal installation.
- Are there any validation
  callbacks that prevent the submit callback to be executed?

Comment: shame on me, clearing cache seems to be the solution. i did not clear cache because before i was editing the module then saving and refreshing the page, its working, but then suddenly it is not,. thank you though for your response :)

Comment: Nice. You're welcome. Maybe you could accept the answer since there was actually no problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

For drupal 7 there are three arguments with form alter.

```
function hook_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // your code
}
```

Hope this will work for you...

Comment: Thanks for the response.. :) you can remove $form_id in the parameter if you are not gonna use it. its still gonna work. clearing my cache seems to be the solution to my problem thank you